# GetGroupsForUser - Only returns groups when I send a claims string 0#.W. Why is that?

Tags: rest, claims-based-auth, soap

I'm playing around with SharePoint 2013 soap api - particularly the GetGroupsForUser on my company's sharepoint instance.
It seems that it only returns groups when I send a claims string `i:0#.w|` + `domain\username`.

If I do not send the claims prefix before the domain\username I get an error message like: `<errorstring>User cannot be found</errorstring>`. When I do send the `i:0#.w|` prefix, no problems at all.

Previously to date, I have never needed that when calling this groups api service. Why is that? Seems like maybe a security setup thing on this company's Sharepoint setup?

Comment: I don't have an answer or know if anything changed, but assuming the web application is using claims I can't imagine it not working without using the claims identifier. Other SharePoint APIs like the server-side API expect the claims identifier for claims users.

Comment: you seem to know a lot about it. perhaps the answer is education on the claims identifier. how it works, what versions of sharepoint it applies to, etc?

Comment: Thanks. The answer very well could be that the API changed, but since I'm not familiar with it I can't provide more than what is essentially a guess.